# Multi matching wildcard text using Olivere Golang package

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kibana, elastic-stack

I have to apply search on two fields, and I have a wildcard text to search. if the text is found in either of the fields that should result in a hit. I am using Olivere golang package.

I tried a combination of should and wildcard query but it is not showing the desired result.
Any help with a code syntax is much appreciated.

```
boolQuery := elastic.NewBoolQuery()
boolQuery = boolQuery.Should(elastic.NewWildcardQuery(email , "*"+text+"*"))
boolQuery = boolQuery.Should(elastic.NewWildcardQuery(name, "*"+text+"*"))
```

this is the query, then i am searching an index

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: updated the query in the question. I think i am not writing the query correctly, i was unable to find any help from the documentation.